# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

Tags: asp.net, xss, viewstate, jmeter, antiforgerytoken

I use asp.net + MVC1.0 and in a web-page I have several forms, within each forms I have called the following function AntiForgeryToken() to generate a hidden value, and in Controller function I have a validate attribute.

When I use JMeter and capture the token using regular expression then post the token with my form to server, I found it throw such a exception:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

[FormatException]: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.AntiForgeryDataSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
[HttpAntiForgeryException]: A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.
   at System.Web.Mvc.AntiForgeryDataSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is configured to show verbose error messages using <customErrors mode="Off"/>. Consider using <customErrors mode="On"/> or <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/> in production environments.
```

And I am sure the the captured token is exactly same as what we generated, why this exception happened?

Comment: Can you actually print out the base-64 string in question? Its fairly simple to check to see if its correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved, because I didn't encode the token before post to server .